# How to fix overflowed issue in Dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I added Dialog, But overflowed on bottow. How to fix like this issue? 
**return showDialog**

```
 return showDialog(
        //  barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return  Dialog(
            //this right here
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData().copyWith(
                inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ), ),
```

**Container in child**

```
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
```

**first Row**

```
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child: Text(AppTranslations.of(context).text("minimum_length")),),
                          Text(": 6")
                        ],),
```

**others rows same like first row**

**Padding for gray color Allowed text**

```
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                            AppTranslations.of(context).text("allowed_character"),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                              ), ),],),),),
```

**OK button**

```
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(child:
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text(
                              AppTranslations.of(context).text("ok"),
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                          ),),],)],),),),), );
```

[image: without rotate]

[image: with rotate]

Comment: Share full code

Comment: I addded full code

Answer (score 9):

For the horizontal overflow add a `Expanded` parent widget for your `Text`.

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(AppTranslations.of(context).text("minimum_length")),
        ),
        Text(": 6")
      ],
    ),
```

And for the vertical overflow add `SingleChildScrollView` parent for your `Column`

```
   Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView( child : Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[ ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working.. Another overflowed issue on botton in dialog.

Comment: Did you add the singlechildscrollview to your column?  If it yes, update the code in your question and show the image

Comment: I cant edit my post...when click edit button 500 error coming

Comment: did you add `SingleChildScrollView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Dialog child element, that is the Container Widget with `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ....
          ....
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```